# Cannot access product page in font office - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: module, prestashop, fatal-error, prestashop-1.7, uncaught-exception

Not sure what happened, but out of a sudden I am not able access the product page when I click on a product in my prestashop FO.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: CartPresenter can only present instance of Cart in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\src\Adapter\Presenter\Cart\CartPresenter.php:315 Stack trace: #0
C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\FrontController.php(501):PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Cart\CartPresenter->present(NULL) #1
C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\FrontController.php(567):FrontControllerCore->assignGeneralPurposeVariables() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\Controller.php(306):FontControllerCore->initContent() #3
C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\Dispatcher.php(518): ControllerCore->run() #4
C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #5
{main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\src\Adapter\Presenter\Cart\CartPresenter.php on line 315
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the shopping cart module, but nothing changes. I couldn't find any other solutions anywhere for this.

What can I try next?

Comment: May be you should try to clear cookies